# What's a good practice for ensuring knockout variables are not manipulated?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've got some simplified code that helps perform some calculations on the client side. The data will be validated on the server side. However, I have noticed it is possible to use the chrome developer console to run knockout observables with new values. Consider this example:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.GuestCounts = ko.observableArray([0, 1, 2, 3])
  self.GuestCount = ko.observable();
  self.PricePerGuest = ko.observable(10); // Retrieved from server and validated on server
}

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

RSVP For <select data-bind="options: GuestCounts(), value: GuestCount"></select>

Total Price: <span data-bind="text: PricePerGuest() * GuestCount()"></span>
```

What can I do to stop someone from opening the developer console, and typing `self.PricePerGuest(1)` or `self.Guests(10000)`

(Note: This doesn't seem to work in the Stack Overflow snippet creator)

Comment: Since you have server-side validations, why do you even care? Front-end validations are only supposed to enhance the UX of non-deviant users. In any case you are simply not able to secure a front-end from manipulation. As you know, JS runs on the end-users browser

Comment: That's just how it is with client side code. You're handing your code over to someone else and hoping that they execute it without modification. Never ever trust it, and never give them an opportunity to do anything with it other than display information on their screen.

Comment: Have you tried minifying (if that's an option for you) your scripts before rendering as it can make it a difficult thing to modify your original script. Nevertheless, you would like to validate it one more time on the server, you don't have an option of being naive :-)